# Calling Another Class Function Within Another Class

Tags: php, class

I've looked everywhere for this question but unable to get an answer.  I'm trying to call another class function within another.  My goal is to have a global class that handles messages.  I want to be able to add message inside other classes. This is my example I'm working with.

```
class Site {
    var $message;

    public function setMessage($string) {
      $this->message .= $string;
    }

    public function outputMessage($string) {
      echo $this->message;
    }

}
```

And my other class

```
class Company {
    var $name;

    public function setName($string) {
      $this->name.= $string;

      // TESTING HERE
      Site::setMessage("Company Set: " .$string);
    }
}
```

Then I have my main page

```
$Site = new Site();
$Site->addMessage("Start");

$Company = new Company();
$Company->addName('Company X');

$Site->outputMessage();
```

I'm trying to get my screen to say "Start Company Set: Company X".  So the site can keep any messages any class needs to store.

I've tried turning the function into a static one without any luck. No matter what I try, I get some kind of error.

For Example:
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Company::$name

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: First of all - there's no `addMessage` method in `Site` class. As `addName` in `Company`. Second - as method called statically - there's no `this`,

Comment: If you want to call a method from another class, you need to include that class before trying to call it. And also make sure that the method you are calling is `public`.

Comment: Sorry, that is suppose to be setMessage.  I have edited the question to show the correct function.  I have tried changing setCompany to a static function and using 

Address::company = $string;

But I get another error:  Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Company::$name.  Also currently, these classes are in the same file.  I don't think I need to include anything.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my reservations of this pattern, you really want the `Site` class to be a singleton:

```
class Site {
    private static $instance = new Site();

    public static getInstance() {
        return Site::$instance;
    }

    private $message;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    public function addMessage($message) {
        $this->message .= $message;
    }

    public static function addNewMessage($message) {
        $instance->addMessage($message);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Site::addNewMessage('...')` or access the instance of `Site` via `Site::getInstance()`.

Comment: `private function __construct`

Comment: @u_mulder: Thanks for catching that. I always screw up the constructors in PHP.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me.  Very much appreciated.
However, Im getting an error on the first line you have inside the class. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)

Comment: Forgot you can't do that in PHP. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing the class to the other.  I could not get the above working.  If anyone has any other way, please let me know.  Thank you again.

```
class Company {
    private $Site;
    var $name;

    function __construct(Site $Site) {
        $this->Site = $Site;
    }

    public function addMessage ($string) {
        $this->Site->addMessage($string);
    }

    public function setName($string) {
        $this->name.= $string;

        // TESTING HERE
        $this->Site->addMessage($string);
    }
}

$Site = new Site();
$Site->addMessage("Start");

$Company = new Company($Site);
$Company->addName('Company X');

$Site->outputMessage();
```